# Accessibility element not a descendant in UI Testing

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UITextField inside a UIView loaded from a nib, it has `isAccessiblityElement` set to true, all of it's superviews do not have it set. It has an `accessbilityIdentifier` set to `Search Field`.

The view is loaded from the nib, and set to a navigationItem's `titleView`.
However when doing UI Testing I can't find the element using the identifier.

Printing a debugDescription of the whole hierarchy of descendants from the root of the app only shows up to the view loaded from the nib, even though it isn't an accessibility element. There is no element anywhere in the hierarchy that has the identifier `Search Field`.

Is there something else that needs to be done to make the `UITextField` appear in the hierarchy and become an queryable ui element, so that UI tests can interact with it.

Comment: Make sure the UIView has isAccessibilityElement = false

Comment: Do you change text of your UITextField programmatically? Can you post code where you change it?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently dealt with a similar problem. In Xcode 9 I've ran into an issue where nested UI elements were unable to be found during UI Automation.

This was fixed by unchecking Accessibility "Enabled" within the Interface Builder for any "container" UIViews.

[image]

After doing this to **ALL** views containing the UI Object it finally accessible in UI Automation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the main view is AccessibilityElement, then the subviews's aren't accessible in UITests.
You need to make the main view's `isAccessibilityElement` false in order to access inner elements.